# Compress Unit ID Permutations

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations, data-analysis

For my multiplayer RTS game, I need to send over the ID's of a player's units selected in a single integer.

For every player, there are 16 units, each with an integer ID between 1-16 (inclusive), and all units of a player have a unique ID.

If anywhere from 1 to 16 units can be selected, what's an efficient way of compressing the units' IDs into 1 integer to send over the network? Then, when this integer reaches another client, how can it be translated back to a list of unit ID's?

Comment: Write it as an (up to) $16$ digit binary number with each bit indicating if that unit is in the list.  Translate this into a decimal integer from $1$ to $65535$ if that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention I'd like this to be as small as possible. Given that the units have unique IDs, it's possible to exclude an ID if it's already used (if the first unit is 15, the second unit can't have the same ID). Then there would be significantly less combinations - less data to send. Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with this - I was hoping the smart people here could help me with the solution.

Comment: @user...:Henry has answered your question. Let me illustrate his idea: let as assume units 2, 5 and 11 are selected units. Consider the corresponding powers of 2 and add them: $4+32+2048=2084$ is the compressed single number you have to send. To decompress, express this as binary and note the position of 1's in that binary string. (taking the least significant bit as position zero). This is exactly  the idea in the unix command chmod.

Comment: I know how to compress data this way. My point is that this could be done a lot more efficiently considering IDs are unique.

Comment: There are $65535$ possible different selections of one to sixteen individuals from a set of $16$.  You want to be able to distinguish then.  So you cannot do better than sending an integer with $65535$ possible different values.

Comment: No, there are 16! because the IDs are unique. Actually, there are less than that because for each branch except the first, there is an additional possibility - no unit at all but if this is the route then none after will be chosen (if there is no Nth unit, there is no (N+1)th unit). I need help finding a formula to compress and decode the data considering the fact that IDs are unique.